# Mysql.. how to combine these 3 requests in a single request?

Tags: mysql

To get my final table, I have to do 3 table creation to get the result..how to combine these 3 requests in a single request?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pturf1.scoring_chev_1;
CREATE TABLE scoring_chev_1 AS 
SELECT comp, jour, idche, cheval, cl, 
sum(case when `cl` = '1er' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as Top_1, 
sum(case when `cl` = '2e' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as Top_2,
sum(case when `cl` = '3e' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as Top_3,
FROM pturf1.cachedate
WHERE (typec ="plat"
AND    jour BETWEEN "2019-08-01" AND "2020-10-01")
GROUP BY comp, idche;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pturf1.scoring_chev_2;
CREATE TABLE scoring_chev_2 AS
SELECT idChe, cheval, (Top_1+Top_2+Top_3)AS total_che
FROM pturf1.scoring_chev_1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pturf1.scoring_cheval;
CREATE TABLE scoring_cheval AS
SELECT idChe, cheval, SUM(total_che) AS total_chev
FROM pturf1.scoring_chev_2
GROUP BY idChe;
```

how to combine these 3 requests in a single request?

Comment: Create stored procedure with this queries. Now one `CALL` request will execute all 6 queries.

Comment: @Akina I think they're actually asking how to create the final table without creating the intermediate tables first.

Comment: @Barmar OP may combine 3 SELECTs into one - but noway combine DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE. So only SP is a solution of "one request - all actions".

Comment: I think you're approaching the problem the wrong way around :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SELECT` queries as subqueries instead of creating tables.

```
CREATE TABLE scoring_cheval AS
SELECT idChe, cheval, SUM(total_che) AS total_chev
FROM (
    SELECT idChe, cheval, (Top_1+Top_2+Top_3)AS total_che
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT comp, jour, idche, cheval, cl, 
        sum(case when `cl` = '1er' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as Top_1, 
        sum(case when `cl` = '2e' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as Top_2,
        sum(case when `cl` = '3e' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as Top_3
        FROM pturf1.cachedate
        WHERE (typec ="plat"
        AND    jour BETWEEN "2019-08-01" AND "2020-10-01")
        GROUP BY comp, idche
    ) AS scoring_chev_1
) AS scoring_chev_2
GROUP BY idChe;
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM pturf1.cachedate
        WHERE (typec ="plat"
        AND    jour BETWEEN "' at line 11

Comment: You had an extra `,` after `Top_3` and I simply copied that.

Comment: Weren't you getting the same error with your original code?

Comment: I assumed the original code worked, I didn't examine it closely.

Comment: You must have copied it wrong then, because it can't work with that comma.